# most efficient way of finding reengaged users

Tags: mysql

i want to get all active users in the past 24 hours, and see whether they've interacted with us before. i have the following query:

```
SELECT $                                                                                                                                                                             
    DISTINCT user_id $                                                                                                                                                               
FROM $                                                                                                                                                                               
    activity $                                                                                                                                                                
WHERE user_id in (SELECT $                                                                                                                                                           
                      DISTINCT user_id $                                                                                                                                             
                  FROM $                                                                                                                                                             
                      activity $                                                                                                                                              
                  WHERE $                                                                                                                                                            
                      date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) AND $                                                                                                                
      date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR);
```

i have indexes on user_id and date. can this be made more efficient?

Comment: All most same statement is running inside user_id in! why don't you try just that statement which you have put inside it. Use Explain

Comment: i did, it was going through too many rows. this is why i came to SO

Answer (score 0):

chris put me in the right track when he instructed me to use `EXISTS`. the correct query is:

```
SELECT $                                                                                                                                                                                 DISTINCT user_id $                                                                                                                                                               FROM $                                                                                                                                                                               
    activity o $                                                                                                                                                              
WHERE $                                                                                                                                                                              
    EXISTS (SELECT $                                                                                                                                                                 
                1 $                                                                                                                                                                  
            FROM $                                                                                                                                                                   
                activity i $                                                                                                                                                  
            WHERE $                                                                                                                                                                  
                o.user_id = i.user_id AND $                                                                                                                                          
                DATEDIFF(o.date, i.date) > 0) AND $                                                                                                                                                           
    date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)$
```

explain mentioned rows examined went from 20k to 170

Comment: hello, `LIMIT 1` is not required. MySQL automatically break sub-query when first row matches when `EXISTS` is used.

Comment: Thanks. Looks better! BTW, I wonder if you test two queries in my answer which is faster? would you mind?

Comment: @InoSHeo replied to your post

Answer (score 0):

could you try this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM activity INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT user_id
        FROM activity
        WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
            AND date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR
    ) x ON x.user_id = activity.user_id
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM activity a1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM activity a2
    WHERE a2.user_id = a1.user_id
      date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))
      AND date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR
);
```

Comment: 2nd query: | 1  | PRIMARY            | a1    | index | 0                        | activity_fbfc09f1 | 4       | 0                  | 29801 | Using where |

Comment: first query has confusing paranthesis after INTERVAL 24 HOUR)) which breaks query

Comment: @tipu Oops. Thanks. have updated. `HOUR))` to `HOUR)`